# Why I am unable to get query parameters from Firebase deep link url in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to get query params from this 
short dynamic link : https://easyloans.page.link/test

Long Dynamic Link : https://easyloans.page.link/?link=https://www.availfinance.in&apn=com.avail.easyloans.android&utm_campaign=Test_Campaign_Name&utm_medium=Test_Medium&utm_source=Test_Source

Manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".Activites.DynamicLink">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="easyloans.page.link"
                android:scheme="http"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:pathPattern=".*"/>
            <data
                android:host="easyloans.page.link"
                android:scheme="https"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:pathPattern=".*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In Android Activity:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
    .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
            // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
            Uri deepLink = null;
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                Log.d(TAG, "source : " + pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink().getQueryParameter("utm_source"));
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "link " + deepLink);

        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
        }
    });
```

Output which i am receiving is : 
link https://www.availfinance.in
and source : null (I am expecting **Test_Source** in this)

Comment: Thanks for the really well written question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getLink()` method returns the `link` parameter you set on the long FDL, which in your example link was just what was returned: *link=https://www.availfinance.in*.

The UTM parameters are passed automatically to Google Analytics for Firebase.

`pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink().getQueryParameter("foo")` will return a value only if it is on the URL contained within the `link` parameter, e.g. if your link was *link=https://www.availfinance.in/?foo=bar* (with appropriate URL encoding).

Comment: So, when we create link from Firebase Console, the FDL is generated automatically based on the params which we provide in "Campaign tracking, social tags and advanced options (optional)" section. Shouldn't this be handled automatically? 
It seems i am not creating URL in a correct way then. Can you guide me through this?

Comment: There is a section in the console with name "**Set up your Dynamic Link**". There we provide deep link url. In this case i have provided https://www.availfinance.in. So should i put the url in link=https://www.availfinance.in/?foo=bar format ?

Comment: @PrashantJha Can you explain how it worked for you, because I am facing similar issue.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @PrashantJha I created the Dynamic link exactly the same way you did and provided params in "Campaign tracking, social tags and advanced options (optional)" section. Now I want to retrive value or utm_medium in this onSuccessListenerr just like you tried                 Log.d(TAG, "source : " + pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink().getQueryParameter("utm_source"));. Is this not possible? If not then how and where do I retrieve these params inside my app?